# How to auto-select the p-drodown Option from Ts functionality? - Angular PrimeNG

Tags: angular, onclick, primeng, p-dropdown

```
<p-dropdown
                  class="form-right-column mt-6"
                  [options]="states"
                  filterBy="name"
                  [formControl]="$any(formGroup).get('state')"
                  optionLabel="name"
                  [editable]="true"
                  (onFilter)="customFilter($event)"
                  placeholder="Select State"
                ></p-dropdown>
```

I have this and I am triggering another click function which is

```
<p-button
                    (click)="confirm($event)"
                    icon="pi pi-check"
                    label="Confirm"
                  ></p-button>
```

I want to write autos elect to Gujarat state if this button clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `patchValue` to do this!

```
confirm(event: any) {
    const stateCtrl = this.formGroup.get('state');
    if(stateCtrl) {
        // if you are using an id then patch value the gujarat id instead!
        stateCtrl.patchValue('Gujarat', { emitEvent: false }); // this can be the key of the dropdown
        // if above does not work you can try
        // const gujarat = this.options.find((x: any) => x.name === 'Gujarat') ||  null;
        // if(gujarat) {
        //     stateCtrl.patchValue(gujarat, { emitEvent: false });
        // }
    }
}
```